# Running multiple FE in Stata

Tags: stata, panel-data

So I have data from ~400 cities and 15 years.  I am trying to do a regression of y on x  and z with fixed effects for these.  I have been trying

```
xi: regress y x z i.city i.year
```

But that tells me matsize too small.  I can do

```
xtreg y x z i.year, fe
```

But that only accounts for year FE.  If I do i.city I get an error that matsize is too small.

What is the best method for doing time and city fixed effects?

Answer (score 2):

Stata lacks a native command to estimate two-way fixed effects models.

I would try

```
xtset city year
xtreg y x z i.year, fe
```

The city effects are differenced out by the demeaning transformation, but they are taken care off. If you care to see them, type `predict fe, u` after the estimation step.

As far as user-written commands, type `findit two-way fixed effects`, which turns up 5 different packages to choose from. There is a nice comparison of some of them [here](http://economics.mit.edu/files/8529) (`reg2hdfe`, `a2reg`, and `felsdvreg`).

Comment: It tells me 'repeated time values within panel' for the xtset

Comment: This means you have at least one city appearing twice is some year. Is your data annual?

Comment: Yes my data is annual.  I do not know if there are some city names that appear twice for different states

Comment: Try `duplicates tag city year, gen(dups)`, followed by `edit if dups>0`. Or create new city-state variable and use that.

Comment: every one of my cities has dups = 3

Comment: That probably means that your data is not annual.

Comment: ahhhh.  I see that it is quarterly.  I have quarter = 0,1,2,3 for each year

Comment: Use a combination of year and quarter instead of year in xtset.